# Implementing custom HTML, CSS and JS for an ADFS SSO login page

Tags: adfs, adfs4.0

I have implemented `ADFS 4.0` on a corporate intranet using `Windows Server 2016`, but I am unhappy with how Microsoft provided logon page looks. I have customized some elements through the use of `PowerShell`, but what I really want to do is take a custom logon page I built using the `bootstrap` front-end framework and implement it as the `ADFS` logon page.

Is this possible with `ADFS 3.0`? This doesn't appear to be as straight forward as I would have though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to customise the login pages for any ADFS > v2 is to use onload.js.